# Install pfSense via KVM in Ubuntu 18.04 w/ netplan

Tags: networking, kvm-switch, pfsense, ubuntu-18.04

I am trying to set up a virtualized firewall for my home network. Architecture looks like: Internet -> virtualized pfSense -> lan. There are plenty of examples of how to do this using the old network configurator, but no examples for using netplan, Ubuntu 18.04's network manager.

I have two NIC cards on the host and freshly installed ubuntu 18.04 server edition installed.

Here is the contents of the /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml file

```
username@scarif:~$ cat /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml
network:
    version: 2
    renderer: networkd
    ethernets:
        eno1:
            dhcp4: no
            dhcp6: no
        enp5s0:
            dhcp4: no
            dhcp6: no

    bridges:
        br_wan:
            interfaces: [enp5s0]
            dhcp4: no
            dhcp6: no
            addresses: [10.0.0.1/24]
        br_lan:
            interfaces: [eno1]
            dhcp4: no
            dhcp6: no
            addresses: [192.168.1.29/24]
            gateway4: 192.168.1.1
            nameservers:
              addresses: [192.168.1.1,8.8.8.8]
```

Note that I believe I need to have a static IP assigned to the LAN bridge, and I want the virtualized pfSense to solicit a DHCP address from the ISP, thus I have assigned a throw away IP to the WAN bridge, and have purposely not assigned a gateway or nameserver to the WAN bridge. (Happy to be corrected on this netplan configuration if this is wrong)

I thought that i needed to create a second virtual bridge, so i have done that as well. I am showing both the default (aka the LAN) and the one i created which i named wan_bridge

```
username@scarif:~$ sudo virsh net-dumpxml default
<network>
  <name>default</name>
  <uuid>5e5d35c8-c46a-43ed-9fc4-13dcb3853b34</uuid>
  <forward mode='nat'>
    <nat>
      <port start='1024' end='65535'/>
    </nat>
  </forward>
  <bridge name='virbr0' stp='on' delay='0'/>
  <mac address='52:54:00:dc:57:8f'/>
  <ip address='192.168.122.1' netmask='255.255.255.0'>
    <dhcp>
      <range start='192.168.122.2' end='192.168.122.254'/>
    </dhcp>
  </ip>
</network>

username@scarif:~$ sudo virsh net-dumpxml wan_bridge
<network>
  <name>wan_bridge</name>
  <uuid>37a0163b-ae70-445d-a25f-c62cbe7d5b51</uuid>
  <forward mode='nat'>
    <nat>
      <port start='1024' end='65535'/>
    </nat>
  </forward>
  <bridge name='virbr1' stp='on' delay='0'/>
  <mac address='52:54:00:dc:57:8d'/>
  <ip address='192.168.133.1' netmask='255.255.255.0'>
  </ip>
</network>
```

Both show up just fine in virsh net-list

```
username@scarif:~$ sudo virsh net-list
 Name                 State      Autostart     Persistent
----------------------------------------------------------
 default              active     yes           yes
 wan_bridge           active     yes           yes
```

I also see both in brctl

```
username@scarif:~$ sudo brctl show
bridge name     bridge id               STP enabled     interfaces
br_lan          8000.aefa52b9a49b       no              eno1
br_wan          8000.22c9e0f24ba3       no              enp5s0
virbr0          8000.525400dc578f       yes             virbr0-nic
virbr1          8000.525400dc578d       yes             virbr1-nic
```

Running ifconfig after all this results in:

```
username@scarif:~$ ifconfig
br_lan: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.29  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::acfa:52ff:feb9:a49b  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether ae:fa:52:b9:a4:9b  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 20623  bytes 3453527 (3.4 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 36  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 4756  bytes 5192472 (5.1 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

br_wan: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.0.0.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.0.0.255
        inet6 fe80::20c9:e0ff:fef2:4ba3  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 22:c9:e0:f2:4b:a3  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 13  bytes 650 (650.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 26  bytes 1996 (1.9 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

eno1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 98:90:96:be:eb:02  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 22673  bytes 4163339 (4.1 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 9632  bytes 5540146 (5.5 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 20  memory 0xf7d00000-f7d20000

enp5s0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 68:1c:a2:12:f8:e9  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 849  bytes 128644 (128.6 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 26  bytes 1996 (1.9 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 347  bytes 26756 (26.7 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 347  bytes 26756 (26.7 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

virbr0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.122.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.122.255
        ether 52:54:00:dc:57:8f  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

virbr1: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.133.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.133.255
        ether 52:54:00:dc:57:8d  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

But when i got to install pfSense with this command string:

```
sudo virt-install \
--name pfsense \
--memory 2048
--graphics vnc,listen=0.0.0.0 \
--disk /var/lib/libvirt/images/pfsense.qcow2,size=8,format=qcow2 \
--autostart \
--os-type linux\
--cdrom /home/dooguls/pfSense-CE-2.4.4-RELEASE-amd64.iso \
--debug
```

The install goes fine, but pfsense only sees one interface, the one provided by the default network, which is my LAN interface/bridge.

Comment: Have you had success running pfSense as an Ubuntu VM? I'm curious about how you've assigned static IPs to your interfaces. Have you kept this configuration if you still run this service?

Answer (score 1):

After typing all the question out, I realized the problem was that the VM wasn't configured to 'see' another interface. So to fix the problem, I did the following:

```
sudo virsh dumpxml pfsense > 20181201-pfsense.txt
```

which of course gives the full xml definition of my VM. I then copied the existing interface entry:

```
<interface type='bridge'>
    <mac address='52:54:00:3a:37:7d'/>
    <source bridge='br_lan'/>
    <model type='rtl8139'/>
    <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x03' function='0x0'/>
</interface>
```

and copied it to make a new interface by running this command:
    sudo virsh edit pfsense

and adding these lines: (note that i changed the mac address by one bit, and assigned the virtual nic to slot 0x06)

```
<interface type='bridge'>
    <mac address='52:54:00:3a:37:7e'/>
    <source bridge='br_wan'/>
    <target dev='vnet1'/>
    <model type='rtl8139'/>
    <alias name='net1'/>
    <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x06' function='0x0'/>
</interface>
```

Then all i had to do was start up the pfsense VM and assign my interfaces to WAN and LAN. WAN grabbed a DHCP from the ISP, and I set a static IP on the LAN interface.

So in the end I think the three key steps on the hypervisor/host were:

1. Set up two bridges in netplan, one for each NIC card and assign the
   IP addresses to the bridges, not the physical NIC cards.
2. Create a new virtual network using virsh net-define not virsh net-create. (the former makes it persistent)
3. Add the second interface to the XML definition of the VM and point this interface at the WAN bridge.